# Expanding input box using only css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an search input box that expands to left when focussed, just like Google's mobile website. I am trying to **do this using css only**.

Search box when not focussed in Safari (mac/iOS). white-space at left is for company logo. Notice that there is no white space between input text box and search button.
Input box has `position:absolute, left:120px, right:80px`.

[image: Search box when not focussed on Safari]

Search box when focussed. I change the `left` of input box to `0` on `input:focus`.

[image: Search box upon focussing]

Search box when not focussed on Firefox. Conflicting absolute position values `left:120px, right:80px` result in whitespace between input text box and button on Chrome/Firefox.

[image: Search box when not focussed on Firefox]

What can I do create such a left expanding input box using css only and without specifying constant value for `width`.

Here is a **[working sample on Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXKbGe)**.

Here is the code...

```css
header {
  padding: 0;
}
input[type='text'] {
  left: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 77px;
  top: 0;
  transition-duration: 100ms;
}
input[type='text']:focus {
  left: 0;
  transition-duration: 300ms;
}
input[type='submit'] {
  background: #1352ec;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <form method="get" action="/search">
        <input class="clearable" type="text" value="ipad"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use CSS `table`, see the following demo. Note, I added a `<span>` around each `<input>`, that is for set up the `table-cell`.

The benefit of using `table-cell` is - we can set one cell to 100% width (for input box), and the other cell will get a minimal width to fit the content inside automatically (for the button).

```css
form {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
span {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: right;
}
span:first-child {
    width: 100%;
}
input[type='text'] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s;
    -moz-transition: width 1s;
    transition: width 1s;
    width: 50%;
    height: 30px;
}
input[type='text']:focus {
    width: 100%;
}
input[type='submit'] {
    background: #1352ec;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4685f9 0%, #1659e1 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4685f9 0%, #1659e1 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4685f9 0%, #1659e1 100%);
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 0;
    width: 80px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <form method="get" action="/search">
        <span><input class="clearable" type="text" value="ipad" name="q" autocomplete="off" /></span>
        <span><input type="submit" value="Search" /></span>
    </form>
</header>
```

Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6mn6be2j/

**EDIT:** updated demo with logo included, CSS [`calc()`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) involved.

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
form {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
span {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: right;
}
span:first-child {
    width: 100%;
}
input[type='text'] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s;
    -moz-transition: width 1s;
    transition: width 1s;
    width: calc(100% - 120px);
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
input[type='text']:focus {
    width: 100%;
}
input[type='submit'] {
    background: #1352ec;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4685f9 0%, #1659e1 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4685f9 0%, #1659e1 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4685f9 0%, #1659e1 100%);
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 0;
    width: 80px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1><img src="http://placehold.it/120x30"/></h1>
    <form method="get" action="/search">
        <span>
            <input class="clearable" type="text" value="ipad" name="q" autocomplete="off" />
        </span>
        <span>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </span>
    </form>
</header>
```

Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ergdc0r1/

Comment: this does work with width for input set 50%. However with a logo of fixed size appearing on left of input box, I will always have some whitespace left between logo and input. demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6mn6be2j/1/

Comment: HI @vikkun I updated the answer added a possible solution that has logo included, the demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/ergdc0r1/

Answer (score 2):

Setting an input's width through `right` and `left` seems to be a bit problematic in most browsers.

To make this work, we need to use a couple of horrible hacks.

The first hack is to wrap the input in a `.wrapper` div. The input's width is then made 100%, and the **wrapper** is given the absolute positioning and the left and right values. This will make the input's initial size correct according to your question.

The second hack is for when we :focus the input. CSS doesn't (yet) allow us to style the wrapper based on whether or not the child is focused. To get around this, we can target the child input and make it intentionally overflow the wrapper. The [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) here lets us specify an exact amount to overflow by. If that doesn't work on your browser, using `110%` here should be fine too.

```
.wrapper input:hover {
  width: calc( 100% + 30px );
}
```

## Demo

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100px;
  left: 10px;
}
.wrapper input {
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 1000ms;
}
.wrapper input:focus {
  width: calc( 100% + 50px );
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input>
</div>
```

Comment: I myself went with 'calc' function first up but the browser support for calc made me change my mind. http://caniuse.com/#search=calc I am going to give this one more shot using the code that you suggest.

Comment: although this does not match my needs exactly, but using `width` in percentages with `calc()` is the right way to go. Browser support needs to be kept in mind though.

Answer (score 1):

***CSS***

```
   header {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
}
input[type='text'] {
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  outline: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 80px;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: width 10s ease;  
    -moz-transition: width 10s ease;  
    -o-transition: width 10s ease;  
    -ms-transition: width 10s ease;  
    transition: width 10s ease;  
  width:200px;
}
input[type='text']:focus {
  width:1000px;

}
input[type='submit'] {
  background: #1352ec;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #4685f9), color-stop(100%, #1659e1));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4685f9 0%, #1659e1 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4685f9 0%, #1659e1 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4685f9 0%, #1659e1 100%);
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: #fff;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 80px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVLYxd)

> I hope this is what you wanted.

The things you done wrong are

1. `Left` property will only help you to move the box and it won't expand the box
2. `left` and `right` both the properties were used on your text box so it created a space between your search button and text box either one should be used be used to place it in correct position and in your case `right` property suits better.
3. to increase the size of the  of the text box use `width` property

Comment: To the `input[type='text']` class you will need to add `width: 300px;` and  `webkit-transition: width 300ms; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: width 300ms;` to get the transition working as well.

Comment: @KawineshSK - yes specifying a constant value for width will help the cause but I'm creating this search box for a mobile site. Hence I have to make use of percentages only. Using width as JoshWillik suggests would be more appropriate in my case.

Comment: @vikkun in that case use width in `%` values and dont use `px` like http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVLYxd